# Can't (re)install MySQL 5.6

Tags: mysql, installation, debian

I have the following problem: I want the install MySQL again (I have deleted the ibdata file, so I was forced to install it again). I have to deleted MySQL by using **apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-common**. Then I have used **apt-get install mysql-server** to install it again.

The installation goes at the beginning fine, but then I recieve an error. Once I have entered the MySQL password on this blue terminal window, I recieve an error.

It is also a blue dialogue. Here's the error:

```
Package configuration


 ┌─────────────────────┤ Configuring mysql-server-5.6 ├──────────────────────┐
 │                                                                           │
 │ Unable to set password for the MySQL "root" user                          │
 │                                                                           │
 │ An error occurred while setting the password for the MySQL                │
 │ administrative user. This may have happened because the account already   │
 │ has a password, or because of a communication problem with the MySQL      │
 │ server.                                                                   │
 │                                                                           │
 │ You should check the account's password after the package installation.   │
 │                                                                           │
 │ Please read the /usr/share/doc/mysql-server-5.6/README.Debian file for    │
 │ more information.                                                         │
 │                                                                           │
 │                                  <Ok>                                     │
 │                                                                           │
 └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

But it is not to only error at all. There are both errors. This error forthcomes, when the MySQL server is trying to start. MySQL can not start, I recieve this error:

```
[....] Starting MySQL database server: mysqldNo directory, logging in with HOME=/
[FAIL. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . failed!
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.6 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.6; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.6 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.6
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Can somebody help me? I despair :(

Thank you!

Comment: did you check if the purge removed the mysql data files? it may remove the DB server, but it could leave the db data files intact (e.g. uninstalling microsoft word doesn't delete all of the .doc files on your computer). if it leaves the db files there, then your original passwords/data/tables/etc.. are all still there.

Comment: And which files and folders I have to delete. I only deleted /etc/mysql by using rm -rf.

Comment: wherever mysql kept the database files. probably /var/lib/mysql somewhere, but you'd have to check your my.ini/my.cnf to confirm. /etc is for config files only, and it'd be highly unlikely the data files were in there.

Comment: I have deleted /etc/mysql and /var/lib/mysql. The installation works, but I recieve these warnings:


egrep: /etc/mysql/: No such file or directory


[....] /etc/init.d/mysql: WARNING: /etc/mysql/my.cnf cannot be read. See README.[warnn.gz ... (warning).
[....] Starting MySQL database server: mysqldNo directory, logging in with HOME=/
. ok
[info] Checking for tables which need an upgrade, are corrupt or were
not closed cleanly..